# Erro ao converter firebase para json com flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Boa tarde pessoal,
Está tela com firebase estava funcionando perfeitamente, porem como criei uma API e estou migrando para json, não estou conseguindo converter está tela e gostaria da ajuda de vocês!

O model:

```
class ScreenListModel {
  final int id;
  final int x;
  final int y;
  final int pos;
  final int id_user;
  final String image;

  ScreenListModel({this.id, this.x, this.y, this.pos, this.id_user, this.image});

  factory ScreenListModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ScreenListModel(
      id: json['id'],
      x: json['x'],
      y: json['y'],
      pos: json['pos'],
      id_user: json['id_user'],
      image: json['image'],
    );
  }
}
```

O dart que recebe os dados:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

const String baseUrl = 'http://192.168.0.187/api/homescreen';

class HomeListData {
  static Future getListData() async {
    return await http.get(baseUrl);
  }
}
```

E a tela:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';
import 'package:transparent_image/transparent_image.dart';



import 'package:apppeccatidigola/datas/homescreen_data.dart';
import 'package:apppeccatidigola/models/homescreen_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class HomeTab extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeTabState createState() => _HomeTabState();
}

class _HomeTabState extends State<HomeTab> {

  var screenlist = new List<ScreenListModel>();

  _getListaScreen(){
      HomeListData.getListData().then((response){
        Iterable listaScreenHome = json.decode(response.body);
        screenlist = listaScreenHome.map((model) => ScreenListModel.fromJson(model)).toList();
      });
  }

  _HomeTabState(){
    _getListaScreen();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Widget _buildBodyBack() => Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                Color.fromARGB(255, 211, 118, 130),
                Color.fromARGB(255, 253, 181, 168)
              ],
              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              end: Alignment.bottomRight
          )
      ),
    );

    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        _buildBodyBack(),
        CustomScrollView(
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              floating: true, //Some a barra
              snap: true, //com floating vai aparecendo a barra
              backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 211, 118, 130),
              pinned: true,
              elevation: 0.0,
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                title: const Text('Novidades'),
                centerTitle: true,
              ),
            ),
            FutureBuilder(
              future: _getListaScreen(),
              builder: (context, snapshot){
                  return SliverStaggeredGrid.count( // count serve para quando se tem um numero exato
                      crossAxisCount: 2, //numero de colunas
                      mainAxisSpacing: 1,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 1,
                      //dimensões das imagens
                      staggeredTiles: screenlist.map((doc){
                        return StaggeredTile.count(doc.data['x'], doc.data['y']);
                      }
                      ).toList(),
                      children: snapshot.data.documents.map((doc){
                        return FadeInImage.memoryNetwork( //faz a imagem aparecer suavimente
                          placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                          image: doc.data['image'],
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        );
                      }).toList()
                  );
              },
            )
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Json:

```
[{"id":1,"image":"https:\/\/as1.ftcdn.net\/jpg\/00\/66\/06\/80\/500_F_66068078_KSdyJchbJ3KqBcdsooLKFdYhsp7fElQO.jpg","x":2,"y":2,"pos":0,"id_user":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{"id":2,"image":"https:\/\/as2.ftcdn.net\/jpg\/01\/06\/76\/35\/500_F_106763503_HVPDhqUbbJbuEpQQDes4ADOrCRGsy806.jpg","x":1,"y":1,"pos":3,"id_user":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{"id":3,"image":"https:\/\/as2.ftcdn.net\/jpg\/00\/59\/29\/77\/500_F_59297786_ANsYzqVG3q8bIdCrItkl7OJImITayvzy.jpg","x":1,"y":1,"pos":2,"id_user":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{"id":4,"image":"https:\/\/as2.ftcdn.net\/jpg\/03\/29\/03\/25\/500_F_329032512_IcHWPOA5g3sENhbV9rKz8fFIRCQVQNCY.jpg","x":1,"y":1,"pos":1,"id_user":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null},{"id":5,"image":"https:\/\/as2.ftcdn.net\/jpg\/03\/20\/43\/37\/500_F_320433797_B2asZKnko8B2rYQ0OaEQbHccUmD9kzjm.jpg","x":1,"y":1,"pos":4,"id_user":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null}]
```

Acredito que o erro esteja neste trecho de código:
staggeredTiles: screenlist.map((doc){
                        return StaggeredTile.count(doc.data['x'], doc.data['y']);

Segue abaixo o erro:

```
Restarted application in 2.003ms.
I/flutter ( 3220): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 3220): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building FutureBuilder<dynamic>(dirty, state:
I/flutter ( 3220): _FutureBuilderState<dynamic>#3bb09):
I/flutter ( 3220): The method 'map' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 3220): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 3220): Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => StaggeredTile)
I/flutter ( 3220): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter ( 3220):   FutureBuilder<dynamic>
I/flutter ( 3220):   file:///home/glauco/Documentos/Desenvolvimento/FlutterProjects/app_peccatidigola/lib/tabs/home_tab.dart:64:13
I/flutter ( 3220): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 3220): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:53:5)
I/flutter ( 3220): #1      _HomeTabState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:apppeccatidigola/tabs/home_tab.dart:72:53)
I/flutter ( 3220): #2      _FutureBuilderState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart)
I/flutter ( 3220): #3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4334:27)
I/flutter ( 3220): #4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4223:15)
I/flutter ( 3220): #5      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
I/flutter ( 3220): #6      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4206:5)
I/flutter ( 3220): #7      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4381:11)
I/flutter ( 3220): #8      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4201:5)
```

Porque quando retiro todo o return do FutureBuilder e deixo um print(screenlist.lenght) aparece a quantidade do json, então está puxando os dados

Comment: Não esta dando certo porque? Qual erro que esta dando? Ajuda a gente te ajudar carinha. **EDITA** a sua pergunta com essas informações

Comment: Editei, adicionei a msg de erro, obg Matheus pela dica.

Answer (score 0):

A falta de atenção é um dos maiores problemas, vamos analisar teu código...

Você chama o seguinte método no seu `FutureBuilder`, que não retorna nada...

```
  _getListaScreen(){
      HomeListData.getListData().then((response){
        Iterable listaScreenHome = json.decode(response.body);
        screenlist = listaScreenHome.map((model) => ScreenListModel.fromJson(model)).toList();
      });
  }
```

Então no seu `FutureBuilder`, você faz a seguinte chamada

```
snapshot.data.documents.map{}
```

Como o seu método não retorna nada, logo sua propriedade `snapshot` vai ser nula, não é?

Então modifique seu `FutureBuilder` da seguinte forma:

```
  FutureBuilder(
    future: _getListaScreen(),
    builder: (context, snapshot){
      return SliverStaggeredGrid.count( // count serve para quando se tem um numero exato
        crossAxisCount: 2, //numero de colunas
        mainAxisSpacing: 1,
        crossAxisSpacing: 1,
        //dimensões das imagens
        staggeredTiles: screenlist.map((doc){
          return StaggeredTile.count(doc.data['x'], doc.data['y']);
        }
        ).toList(),
        children: screenlist.map((doc){
          return FadeInImage.memoryNetwork( //faz a imagem aparecer suavimente
            placeholder: kTransparentImage,
            image: doc.data['image'],
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          );
        }).toList()
      );
    },
  )
```

Outra coisa é, você esta usando o `FutureBuilder` para que? Pois seu método não aguarda por nada, mude para o seguinte:

```
  _getListaScreen() async {
      var response = await HomeListData.getListData()
      Iterable listaScreenHome = json.decode(response.body);
      screenlist = listaScreenHome.map((model) => ScreenListModel.fromJson(model)).toList();
      setState((){});
      });
  }
```

E como seu método já é usado no `FutureBuilder` remova-o do `initState`.

Para seu código ficar realmente correto, faça teu `_getListaScreen()` retornar a lista, e use no `FutureBuilder` o `snapshot.data` ao invés da `screenList`

**Os erros em Flutter são, quase sempre, muito claros e explicativos, leia-os!**